# Pandas create new column which is the mean of values from previous rows

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a working version of what I need it do using groupby and apply, however it is really slow and so I am hoping that a new approach will yield faster results.

Here is a subset of the code that I have been using so far:

```
url = 'https://horse-data-abcd.s3.amazonaws.com/horse_track_code.csv'
temp_df = pd.read_csv(url)

def run_aggs(row):
    return row.shift().expanding() \
    .agg({'win': 'mean' })

df_feature = temp_df.groupby(['horse_aap_id', 'track_code_3']).apply(run_aggs)

columns = {
    'win': f'track_win_sr'
}
df_feature.rename(columns=columns, inplace=True)
temp_df = temp_df.join(df_feature)
```

What I want to do is create a new column `track_win_sr` that is a pd.mean(win) of all the previous rows of the index.

`track_win_sr` is the mean of wins of all previous runs by the horse at the track prior to row. `sr` mean strike rate.

The output then looks like this image.

[image]

The problem that I have is that when it is applied to a large dataset it is really slow, I am looking for an optimisation (perhaps matrix approach) to really speed things up.

Here is a [link to the full file](https://horse-data-abcd.s3.amazonaws.com/horse_track_code_full.csv) to use in the above code to test for speed.

Any advice of help greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Luke

Comment: Could you please format your dataframe in a manner that it can be copied instead of an image (i.e. text)? You should also include your working version of your code you mention in your post. It will add further clarity to your desired output.

Comment: @rahlf23 I have updated with a full dataset and the code.

Comment: could you trim the dataset with just a couple of rows and show an example of what you want your output to be? the dataset is quite large, so do trim it to just a couple of rows.

Comment: @sammywemmy have trimmed the dataset and added an example output

Comment: @LukeByrne, if you dont mind, the file is still large. That aside, what exactly do you want to achieve. Let's put aside your solution for now, could you kindly explain your end goal with an example

Comment: @sammywemmy my end goal is the same as the output from my code, I was just trying to find a faster solution. Maybe it's possible to do it in a matrix style method? I am not sure, I am just putting it out there.

Comment: @LukeByrne, i am really keen to understand the task. what does 'track_win_sr' mean? what is the concept for the calculation? why are you doing a row by row computation in the run_aggs fn? would love to know what you are trying to solve from the root before i, or anyone else can offer any constructive options. More like 'track win snr means this, the calculation is to get bla bla... sth that makes the task clearer. i really cant work with your code if i dont understand what it is you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i come up with:

Lets load it into DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./horse_track_code_full.csv', parse_dates=[2])
df['track_code_3'] = df['track_code_3'].astype('category')
```

With [`DataFrame.expanding()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html?highlight=expanding#pandas.DataFrame.expanding) you will be able to achieve what you need.

```
grouped_expaning_mean = df.groupby(['horse_aap_id', 'track_code_3']).win.expanding().mean()
```

Now we need to "ungroup" the calculated data with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html?highlight=reset_index#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index):

```
ungrouped_expanding_mean = grouped_expanding_mean.reset_index().
```

`groupby()` preserves the order from the original dataframe, so we only need to set appropriate index and sort it:

```
reindexed_win_means = ungrouped_expanding_mean.set_index('level_2').sort_index()
```

All that needs to be done is add it to the column of the original dataframe

```
df['track_win_sr'] = reindexed_win_means.win
```